# how Compare two lists & get match percentage of each element in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I have two lists named mylist and other as show below :-

```
mylist [
{is_selected: true, image: images/pet.png, title: Pet Lover},
 {is_selected: true, image: images/party.png, title: Party}

]


other [

{is_selected: true, image: images/loudmusic.png, title: Music},
 {is_selected: true, image: images/party.png, title: Party}, 
{is_selected: true, image: images/shopping.png, title: Shopping}, 
{is_selected: true, image: images/reading.png, title: Reading}

]
```

I just want to compare there "title" element and get the percentage of matching

Comment: Hey, not sure I understand the question, what exactly do you expect to get as a result? should it be 0.25 because only one of the four titles on `other` match? 0.5 because only one of two match on `mylist`? some other result?

Comment: @h8moss  no I mean if one title matches it show return 10% match if 2 the 20% as i have 10 elements in total